# What does the /shin/ marker (like Petucha/Setuma) at the end of Torah books mean?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, aleph-bet-letters, sefer-torah, vayechi, safrus

I've been reading about details of Torah *sofrut*, and after learning about the paragraph markers *peh* / פ (*petucha*) and *samekh* / ס (*setuma*), I noticed some similarly placed *shin* markers (mostly at the end of a *sefer*), but cannot find an answer in Google searches. What does it stand for? (Example: parsha VaYechi). I'm using an electronic [version from Mechon Mamre](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0150.htm) similar to Keter Yerushalayim / Aleppo Codex.

Comment: sventech, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: I just did a search of Mechon Mamre and asked a friend who has a Koren New Jerusalem Bible. The shin marker *only* appears at the end of a book, making it the Masoretic note indicating just that. In terms of safrus, it means that you skip four lines before starting the next book.

Comment: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0214.htm#31, http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0215.htm#19, These are by *Az Yashir*

Comment: @sharshi what's with the Reish??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following information is recorded on the [Mechon Mamre](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/aboutpsq.htm) website:

> בתנ"כים שלנו יש גם סימני הפרשייות {פ} {ס} {ר} {ש} שהם מסמנים פרשה פתוחה, פרשה סתומה, סוף שורה בשירות מסויימות, ושורה ריקה (או שורות ריקות בסוף ספר).‏

My translation:

> In our Tanakhs there are also [the following] disjunctive symbols: פ,‎
>   ס,‎ ר,‎ ש, which stand for "open break" (פרשה **פ**תוחה), "closed
>   break" (פרשה **ס**תומה), the "end of each line in determined poems"
>   (סוף שו**ר**ה בשירות מסויימות - eg: Exodus 15:1-19) and a "blank line" (or
>   "blank lines at the end of a book" - **ש**ורות ריקות בסוף ספר).

That should answer your question, although I don't know where that tradition stems from. Obviously it's not the Aleppo Codex, since the Aleppo Codex is lacking most of the Torah (and I don't think these details were recorded prior to their being destroyed). I checked Rabbi Prof. Mordechai Breuer's Tanakh and I also checked the BHS, and neither of them recorded this. I have fascimiles of the Aleppo Codex and the Leningrad Codex, and neither record these symbols between other books in Tanakh (nor does the latter record it between Genesis and Exodus).

Finally, I looked at Yeivin's *Tiberian Masorah* and Tov's *Textual Criticism of the Hebrew Bible*, and they don't appear to mention it either. Regrettably, Mechon Mamre does not declare exactly which mss they are employing, save to note that they are close to the Aleppo Codex.

Comment: Thanks, Shimon! That is exactly what I was looking for. Likewise I have no idea where they got that tradition. With regard to the Torah of the Aleppo Codex, my understanding is that Rabbi Prof. Mordechai Breuer's Tanakh is said to follow it closely by comparing other manuscripts alleged to be direct descendants (copies) of it, although only a small part of D'varim is extant.

Comment: @sventech Only a small part of Devarim is extant...from Torah. There is still most of Nach that is also extant.

Comment: Am I reading correctly that ר is for "שירה" and ש is for "ריקה" or is the order switched somewhere?

Comment: You are correct, WAF - I just put the ר and the ש in bold so that you can see. It's not clear to me why they use a ר when the order that you suggest makes more sense.

Comment: @DoubleAA, when I was in Yerushalayim over the summer, I learned that some other leaves from the Torah portion of Keter Aram Soba have survived, including a portion from somewhere near the Kadesh-li.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt There are two small fragments of pages from Shemot that popped up a couple years back, and a photograph of a page in Bereishit. The rest is probably hiding in some Syrian Shul in Brooklyn...

Comment: @DoubleAA, the daf I saw was what I commented on, as it was the only thing I could verify having seen it personally.