# Mechon-Mamre Tanach text

Tags: tanach, internet, text, manuscripts

Which manuscript of the Masoretic text is used as the basis for the Tana"ch on [Mechon-Mamre.org](http://mechon-mamre.org/)?

Is it based on [the Leningradensis](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leningrad_Codex), [the Keter Aram Soba](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleppo_Codex), or another manuscript?

Comment: I started poking around their about pages, but you'd probably get a better answer if you follow the advice at the bottom of [their about page](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/aboutus.htm): "יש לך שאלה או הערה?  נא לכתוב לנו!"

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17539/3

Comment: If you download their text, it has a readme file which contains: "The Hebrew text in this HTML edition of the Hebrew Bible is based on
the Aleppo Codex and the other early manuscripts that are close to it,
using the method of the Rav Mordechai Breuer, taken from our online
version at: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/ " In other words, absent certain extreme subtleties, their version is virtually indistinguishable from the most accurate Masoretic text.

Comment: Though they follow the Rambam about Parshiyot, even against the best testimony of the Keter http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0307.htm http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0527.htm

Comment: In my experience they answer emails very quickly and nicely (and proudly), so I suggest you ask them directly